# Why doesn't this thread get executed?

Tags: c#, sockets, network-programming, client

This a server program I tried but It does not give output. The `Service()` method is not being executed. What changes should I do? I have used C# language.

```
    IPAddress hostIP;
    String hostName;
    Int16 serverPort;

    private static void Service()
    {
        string frmsg = "Hi there client!!";
        Console.WriteLine("Child thread starts SERVICE..."); 
        Console.Write("{0}", frmsg);
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Socket MS_socket,CS_socket;
        EndPoint serverEP;
        IPAddress hostIP;

        serverEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 5555);
        MS_socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        MS_socket.Bind(serverEP);
        MS_socket.Listen(0);
    }
```

Then I believe there is something wrong with this part of code ..

```
  while (true)
  {
            // creating a connection socket.and accepting incoming connection request
            CS_socket = MS_socket.Accept();
            // starts a new thread to process the request
            ThreadStart childref = new ThreadStart(Service);
            Console.WriteLine("In Main: Creating the Child thread");
            // will invoke service method through thread.
  }
```

Where is the problem in this code?

```
Thread childThread = new Thread(childref);
```

Starting the thread ......

```
childThread.Start();
Console.ReadKey();
```

There is a error which I can't figure it out. I get no output.

Comment: It's blocking on the line `CS_socket = MS_socket.Accept();`.

Comment: Do you have a client app that connects to 127.0.0.1:5555?

Comment: Yes I tried with two classes SerListner which listens for requests and SerService which is going service the client.

Comment: @md4 What is that I do?